# Should javac find methods outside of an anonymous class of the same name?

Tags: java, methods, javac, anonymous-class

This question is a follow up to:
[Why can’t I call a method outside of an anonymous class of the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252267/why-cant-i-call-a-method-outside-of-an-anonymous-class-of-the-same-name)

This previous question answer **why**, but now I want to know if javac **should** find run(int bar)?  (See previous question to see why run(42) fails)

If it shouldn't, is it due to a spec?  Does it produce ambiguous code?  My point is, I think this is a bug.  While the previous question explained why this code fails to compile, I feel it should compile if javac searched higher in the tree if it fails to find a match at the current level.  IE.  If this.run() does not match, it should automatically check NotApplicable.this for a run method.

Also note that foo(int bar) is correctly found.  If you give any reason why run(int bar) shouldn't be found, it must also explain why foo(int bar) is found.

```
public class NotApplicable {

    public NotApplicable() {
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                // this works just fine, it automatically used NotApplicable.this when it couldn't find this.foo
                foo(42);

                // this fails to compile, javac find this.run(), and it does not match
                run(42);

                // to force javac to find run(int bar) you must use the following
                //NotApplicable.this.run(42);
            }
        };
    }

    private void run(int bar) {
    }

    public void foo(int bar) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior of javac conforms to the spec. See [§15.12 Method Invocation Expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#20448) in the Java Language Specification, specifically the paragraph under "Compile Time Step 1" explaining the meaning of an unqualified method invocation:

> If the Identifier appears within the scope (§6.3) of a visible method declaration with that name, then there must be an enclosing type declaration of which that method is a member. Let T be the innermost such type declaration. The class or interface to search is T.

In other words, the unqualified method *name* is searched for in all enclosing scopes, and the innermost "type declaration" (which means either a class or an interface declaration) in which the name is found is the one that will be searched for the whole signature (in "Compile Time Step 2").

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand the spec.

Now I can argue that this is a bad spec and should be changed.  Compile Time Step 1 should include the enclosing class of the anonymous class.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a recipe for ambiguity and fragility to me - as soon as a new method is added in your base class (okay, not so likely for an interface...) the meaning of your code changes completely.

Anonymous classes are pretty ugly already - making this bit of explicit doesn't bother me at all.

Comment: Ok, then why is javac allowed to find foo(int bar)?  It is the same recipe.

Comment: That's true. Bah, it's all an ugly mess. Give me proper closures :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NotApplicable.this.run(42);
```

instead.

Comment: Note that at the time I wrote this answer, the comment with this same bit of code in it was not present in the question.